# isValid() method return false in symfony

Tags: symfony

I am using symfony3 with window 7 AND using custom form rending. like that

```
{{ form_start(form,{ 'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal','role':'form','id':'form'} }) }} 

---- form field here

{{ form_widget(form._token) }}
            {{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}



/**
     *  @Route("entity/entity/{id}", name="entity_entity",defaults={"id" = 0})    
     */
    public function entityAction(Request $request,$id){
        $action = false;
        $arr_XYZ_data = array();
        $arr_XYZ_prepare_data = array();       
        $form_title = 'Add New XYZ';
        $obj_XYZ = new XYZ();             
        $form = $this->createForm(XYZType::class, $obj_XYZ);
        if($id!=0){
          $obj_repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:XYZ');
          $arr_XYZ_data = $obj_repo->find($id);         
          if($arr_XYZ_data){
            $action = true;
            $form_title = 'Update XYZ';                   
            $arr_XYZ_data = $obj_repo->findXYZById($id);           
            $arr_XYZ_prepare_data = $this->_prepareData($arr_XYZ_data);
          }
        }
        $form->handleRequest($request);              
        if (($form->isSubmitted())&&($form->isValid())) {          
            $obj_XYZ->setXYZId($id);
            $str_hiddenfield_result = $form->get('extraformfield')->getData();
            $arr_hiddenfield_result = explode('&',$str_hiddenfield_result);     
            $obj_XYZ->setDef($obj_XYZ->getDef()->getDefId()); 
            $obj_XYZ->setAbc($arr_hiddenfield_result[3]); 
            $obj_XYZ->setAuthor(1); //ldap session value
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($obj_XYZ);           
            $em->flush();                 

            $this->addFlash('success',  'Your record has been added successfully!');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('XYZ_index', array(), 301);
        }else{
            $form->getErrors();
        }
    }
```

above code does not print any error but unable to submit. so please anyone can suggest me how can i fix the issue.

how to get all error in string with corresponding each form field.

Comment: Take a look at the web debug toolbar or use $form->getErrors(true)

Comment: you need to explicitly print your error in your else block.

Answer (score 1):

Just calling the getter will not print anything, you need to do it by yourself using another (printing) function.

```
return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response($form->getErrors());
```

It will render a string containing all errors.

Depending on the context (traditional, ajax, ...), you can just re-render the form like so:

```
return $this->render('YourBundle:YourView.html.twig', [
    'form' => $form->createView(),
]);
```

The errors should be properly displayed.